# Button click then open specific position

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an app.
I want a `button` which open `google maps` app with this 
49.019571, 8.412362 position.
Is that possible?
I found nothing.
I hope you can help me.
Only the extra Maps app nothing in the app.

Comment: where will the specific position come from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/) it will help

**Edit** 
If you have specific co-ordinates to which your map should open then you can start the intent by using the following code

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @andrewsi i totally agree. But providing a help for some one who hasn't found anything its better that he reads the whole tutorial what do you say

Comment: I looked at the link, but this one is old. I can`t get the map api key.

Comment: Suggestions that aren't quite answers are often better posted as comments.

Comment: You can please at least extract some of the key elements into your answer? That way if the link goes dead your answer doesn't become useless. Remember, StackOverflow is about accumulating answers to questions, not about solving the poster's problem.

Comment: @ArtB i would have but the question didnt had those points like co-ordinates hence was my answer. As they have been updated I will update my answer.. Thank You

Comment: @MDMalik only reason I commented is because your answer was triggered into the "low quality answer, delete?" moderator queue.

Comment: I already need a well answer :/

Comment: @ArtB Thanks for informing me about this. I have updated my answer to suit the needs the questionaire

Comment: The context at context.startActivity(intent);
is red coloured. Why?